# What does this C struct assignment mean?

Tags: c, struct, variable-assignment

I'm trying to read through some C source code and I've come across a structure assignment that I don't understand:

```
static struct sym_table *sym_array = (struct sym_table *) 0;
```

I understand that the left-hand-side is trying to initialize a pointer to a structure of type 'sym_table' (which is defined elsewhere); however, I am struggling to understand the right-hand-side. It's probably fairly simple, but I can't find any similar examples of this sort of assignment in any of the online C tutorials that I've seen.

If anyone can shed some light on it, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: it's casting the 0 value to the proper pointer type to set to 0. Would be better with `NULL` macro.

Comment: It's casting 0 to be a pointer to that struct, but that's not the right way to do it - using NULL is the preferred way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static struct sym_table *sym_array = (struct sym_table *) 0;
```

is a slightly cumbersome way to set a pointer to `NULL`, `NULL` being defined in `stdio.h` as `((void *)0)`. You'd be better off with:

```
static struct sym_table *sym_array = NULL;
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. Yes, it does seem like quite a long-winded way to set a null pointer :-)

Answer (score 2):

The right-hand-side is the equivalent of NULL pointer. But here , it is a NULL pointer of type (struct sym_table *)

Answer (score 2):

this the  Stroustrup way. He hates macros. So he always uses `0` in his code or eventually when keyword `nullptr` was introduced the `nullptr`. I think it is from the C++ code or from the program written by someone who usually uses C++.

Comment: But I see the C++ soul in it :)

Comment: the advantage of this method is that you don't have to define or include anything. You may be right.